# BasicAck when processing messages asynchronously

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to set up a RabbitMQ messaging queue so that I can send a message to start a long running process and also be able to send a message to cancel that long running process if needed. So I started out with an `EventingBasicConsumer` and did something like this in my `Recieved` handler:

```
if (startProcess) 
{
    // start a long running process
}
else if (cancelProcess)
{
    // cancel the currently running process
}
channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
```

And this doesn't work because the `EventingBasicConsumer` isn't multithreaded and can only handle one message at a time. So it can't handle the cancel message until it's finished with the long running process (at which point, there's no point, obviously). So next I tried this:

```
if (startProcess) 
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        // start a long running process
    }
}
else if (cancelProcess)
{
    // cancel the currently running process
}
channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
```

And this works. I can now cancel the long running process...but, I'm acknowledging the request to run the long running process immediately, rather than after it's completed. This means that if the long running process was to crash, the message has already been removed. So this would require the original sender to keep track and have the receiver have to send messages back to say it's done and it all gets a bit complicated.

So I thought maybe I could change `EventingBasicConsumer` to just always fire its `Received` event on a new thread. So I created something like this:

```
public class AsyncRabbitConsumer : DefaultBasicConsumer
{
    // code all the same as EventingBasicConsumer except this bit:
    public override void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag,
        ulong deliveryTag,
        bool redelivered,
        string exchange,
        string routingKey,
        IBasicProperties properties,
        byte[] body)
    {
        base.HandleBasicDeliver(consumerTag,
            deliveryTag,
            redelivered,
            exchange,
            routingKey,
            properties,
            body);
        if (Received != null)
        {
            var args = new BasicDeliverEventArgs(consumerTag,
                    deliveryTag,
                    redelivered,
                    exchange,
                    routingKey,
                    properties,
                    body);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Received(this, args);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my first snippet of code, I can have it process the cancel message while the long running process is still running *and* the long running process won't Ack and delete it's message until it's actually finished (or cancelled). So that should be great...except when I cancel I get this:

> An exception of type 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException' occurred in RabbitMQ.Client.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 3", classId=60, methodId=80, cause=

From the `channel.BasicAck` step of what appears to be the thread that started the long running process. So what's going on here? I think the acknowledgements (for the cancel message first and then the long running process message) are getting crossed here. Is there any decent way to straighten this out? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

It's probably worth noting that cancelling the long running process is not instantaneous. It will cancel at the next convenient point, so it's almost certain that the cancel message will finish processing before the long running process has ended.

Comment: @Rob: because of exactly the exception I have above.

Comment: Sorry - my bad, I skimmed over that part.

Comment: How are you managing the connections? It looks like your channel is getting disposed, which is what's causing your failures. Also - how many workers are there? If you have more than one, it's possible your second worker is picking up the cancel, and trying to cancel a non-existing task. You can have your worker watch for the cancel on a particular channel, or specify a routing key

Comment: @Rob: The channel is a field in the class. It's not being disposed until the application closes.

Comment: If you cancel the long running process, you want the message requeued or not? I'm assuming yes, but just to be sure...

Comment: @cantSleepNow: Probably no. If the application that had requested the long running process then request to cancel it, it shouldn't be requeued. They would have to ask for the long running process again.

Comment: A already gave an answer but it occurred to me that it might be interesting to know how do you know when you need to sent a cancel message?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have something like consumers pairs - first one that is the long running process, and second one an agent to kill the long running process. First one would receive the messages, process it and ACK when finished processing,also would do ACK also if kill signal is detected. The agent in the pair would obviously receive the cancel message and kill the first one, and also spawn another instance of the first. Clearly this requires the processes(consumers) communicate outside of RMQ.

The other thing that comes to mind (but I have never tried something like this) is that you set the **prefetch count to 2** in the consumer, and while "processing single data message", publish the second message to the broker (forward) unless it's the CANCEL message, in which case you ACK both of them - the CANCEL and the DATA (to call it like that) message, after you have aborted the processing.

Another option perhaps would be that within "long running process" you have two consumer threads with each of them using their own channel.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error because in **BasicConsume** method **autoAck** flag was true. Now i have changed the flag to false and i am not getting error in BasicAck method for long running process.

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "test", autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
```